# Partial derivatives-Why does this stand?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

In my notes there is the following:
$$u_{\xi \eta}=0 \Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix}
u_{\xi}=0 \Rightarrow u=g(\eta)\\ 
u_{\eta}=0 \Rightarrow u=f(\xi)
\end{matrix}\right.$$

I haven't understood why this stand...

Isn't it as followed??

$$u_{\xi \eta}=0 \Rightarrow u_{\xi}=F(\xi) \text{ AND } u_{\xi \eta}=0 \Rightarrow u_{\eta}=G(\eta)$$

Why should $F(\xi)$ and $G(\eta)$ be equal to $0$??

---

**EDIT:**

I found this at the proof of the solution of the wave equation using the characteristics, which is the following:

$$u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}=0$$

$\displaystyle{\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1}{a}(b \pm \sqrt{\Delta})=\pm c}$

$\left.\begin{matrix}
\xi=x-ct\\ 
\eta=x+ct
\end{matrix}\right\}$

$\displaystyle{\partial_x=\partial_{\xi}+\partial_{\eta}}$

$\displaystyle{\partial_t=-c \partial_{\xi}+c \partial_{\eta}}$

$\displaystyle{\partial_{xx}=\partial_{\xi \xi}+\partial_{\eta \eta}+2 \partial_{\xi \eta}}$

$\displaystyle{\partial_{tt}=c^2(\partial_{\xi \xi}+\partial_{\eta \eta}+2 \partial_{\xi \eta})}$

So $\displaystyle{(\partial_{tt}-c^2 \partial_{xx})u=0 \Rightarrow -4c^2 \partial_{\xi \eta}u=0 \Rightarrow}$

$$u_{\xi \eta}=0 \Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix}
u_{\xi}=0 \Rightarrow u=g(\eta)\\ 
u_{\eta}=0 \Rightarrow u=f(\xi)
\end{matrix}\right.$$

$$\Rightarrow u=f(\xi)+g(\eta) \Rightarrow u=f(x-ct)+g(x+ct)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. $u_\xi=F(\xi),\ u_\eta = G(\eta)$. Note that this implies (by integrating) that $u(\xi,\eta) = \widetilde F(\xi) + \widetilde G(\eta)$. You can verify this by trying something simple like $u(\xi,\eta) =\xi+\eta$

Comment: Ahaa..Ok...Could you look at my first post? I have edited it and posted the whole proof, where I have found this part..

Comment: @MaryStar, the rest of the proof looks fine. I assume you just copied wrong into the notes, because right after the line in question you yourself wrote $u=f(\xi)+g(\eta)$ which is correct. So you just need to correct the big bracket.

Comment: Ok! Thank you!!! :-)