# Question about the solution of the wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

The solution of the wave equation
$$u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}=0$$ is given as $$u(x,t)=f(x+ct)+g(x-ct)$$
where $f,g$ are arbitrary functions of one variable.

One way to prove this is the following:

$$(\partial_{tt}-c^2 \partial_{xx})u=0$$
$$(\partial_t-c \partial_x)(\partial_t+c \partial_x)u=0$$

So solutions must satisfy

$$
(\partial_t-c \partial_x)u=0 \;\;\cup\;\; 
(\partial_t+c \partial_x)u=0
$$

$\displaystyle{(\partial_t-c \partial_x)u=0 \Rightarrow u=f(x+ct)}$

$\displaystyle{(\partial_t+c \partial_x)u=0 \Rightarrow u=g(x-ct)}$

---

Could you explain me why the last two equations stand??

Comment: Do you mean the implication with $u = f(x+ct)$ or do you mean
$$
\left.\begin{matrix}
(\partial_t-c \partial_x)u=0\\ 
(\partial_t+c \partial_x)u=0
\end{matrix}\right\}?
$$

Comment: I think it's not the implication, it's more like "notice that $u=f(x + ct)$ works". A more rigorous derivation is in here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/740339/wave-equation-how-to-derive-the-form-ux-t-fxctgxct?rq=1

Comment: Thee proof as you present it is flawed: It is not true that the wave equation implies either of the two first order equations listed. (The opposite implication is OK, though.) The standard way to do it is to change variables into $\xi=x-ct$ and $\eta=x+ct$, then notice that the equation becomes $u_{\xi\eta}=0$, which is easy to solve. (For details, look at the link provided by @PA6OTA.)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I mean the implication $u=f(x+ct)$ and $u=g(x-ct)$.

Comment: @PA6OTA Harald Hanche-Olsen: So we can show that when $\displaystyle{(\partial_t-c \partial_x)u=0}$ it implies that $\displaystyle{u=f(x+ct)}$??

Comment: Yes, it's been covered in the link above.

Comment: Ok...So from the one relation we get $\displaystyle{u=f(x+ct)}$ and from the other one we get $\displaystyle{u=g(x-ct)}$, therefore $$u=\frac{f(x+ct)+g(x-ct)}{2}$$ Is this correct??

Answer (score 2):

$$\displaystyle{(\partial_t-c \partial_x)u=0 \Rightarrow u=f(x+ct)} \text{   (1)}$$

Define $\xi=x+ct$.

The solution of the above equation is called traveling wave solution, because the wave front is the same at constant $\xi=x+ct$.

$$\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial t}=c$$
$$\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x}=1$$

$$\partial_t f(\xi)=\partial_\xi f(\xi)\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial t}=c\partial_\xi f(\xi)$$

$$\partial_x f(\xi)=\partial_\xi f(\xi)\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x}=\partial_\xi f(\xi)$$

Substituting these two quantities into (1) above and we conclude that $f(\xi)$ is a solution of (1).

Define $\eta=x-ct$

Similarly we have:
$$\partial_t g(\eta)=-c\partial_\eta g(\eta)$$

$$\partial_x g(\eta)=\partial_\eta g(\eta)$$

Substituting these two quantities into (2) below and we conclude that $g(\eta)$ is a solution of (2)

$$\displaystyle{(\partial_t+c \partial_x)u=0 \Rightarrow u=g(x-ct)}\text{    (2)}$$

Thus this PDE with a traveling wave solution becomes an ODE.

As a matter of factor, for any PDE that does not explicitly on $x$ or $t$, if you search for traveling wave solution, then you can convert it to an ODE (maybe nonlinear though).

For example, the nonlinear Schrodinger equation:
$$\left(i\partial_t+a (\partial_x)^2\right)\psi(x,t)+ |\psi(x,t)|^2\psi(x,t)=0$$

Comment: Is your proof, the one that uses the characteristics?? (The way I describe in the thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/830962/partial-derivatives-why-does-this-stand/831009?noredirect=1#comment1719550_831009 )

Comment: @MaryStar Your method is the standard method in the text book. I was not aware of your answer when I wrote the answer. So I just used a method that happens to be more general.  Please refer to the last nonlinear equation that we can apply this method to.