# General solution of a wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics, wave-equation, hyperbolic-equations

Consider the wave equation $$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}-c^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}=0\tag{1}$$ which can be written as $$\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-c\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big)\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+c\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big)u=0\tag{2}.$$

The question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833044/question-about-the-solution-of-the-wave-equation) claims that (2) implies both $\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+c\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big)u=0$ as well as $\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-c\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big)u=0$.

I do not get this. Eq. (2) can be satisfied if $\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+c\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big)u=v\neq 0$ and $$\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+c\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big)v=0.$$

Am I missing something?

Comment: You should really open any textbook in PDEs, this is one of the first examples.

Comment: @MyGlasses Question edited.

Comment: I think the last equation $\Big(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}+c\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big)v=0$ is the same $(1)$. is not that?

Comment: @MyGlasses Yes. It is, of course.

Comment: So it is ineffective and we write again 
$$\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+c\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big)\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-c\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big)u=0\tag{3}$$
gives us 
$\Big(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}-c\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big)u=0$

Comment: that claim in the linked question is wrong: any function satisfying either of the two **is** a solution

Comment: @NickPavlov So why don't you correct that ?

Comment: I did, but my suggested edit is pending review